# Zuul Block Headers

Tags: netflix-zuul

I'm trying to recibe an Autorization Header from a Response but Zuul Block it.

I try:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      sensitiveHeaders: Autorization
```

but it doesn't work :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with this configuration in:

> aplication.yml

```
zuul:
  # exclude Authorization from sensitive headers
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```